# Correct way to slice and add newlines at certain points in user input

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a program underway where one of the functions is to take a possibly very long user-supplied string. However, I need to make sure the string breaks up at certain points. I want each line to be no more than 50 characters but it has to break at spaces.

The thing that seems to make sense to me is to run an if function that tests the length of the string, slices it into a 50-character length, finds the last space, and inserts a newline at that point. To me, that makes the code seem clunky. Is there a smoother, more Pythonic way to do this?

```
instr = input()
if len(instr) > 50:
    n = instr[:50].rfind(' ')
    instr.replace(instr[n], "\n")
    n += 50
    if len(instr) > n:
        n = instr[:n].rfind(' ')
        instr.replace(instr[n], "\n")
        n += 50
```

As you can see, that loop could go on and on and on, although I would have it generate an error message if it goes over a certain length. This code will do what I'm asking, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python comes with a [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper) module, which does more or less what you asked for:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

import textwrap
print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(text, width=50)))
```

Note that by default it does more than just splitting on whitespace, you might want to check the docs and tweak some options.

If you'd like to keep using your algorithm, you can simplify it to:

```
n = 50
while len(instr) > n:
    n = instr[:n].rfind(' ')
    instr = instr[:n] + "\n" + instr[n+1:]
    n += 50

print (instr)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized just before checking the question that I should not be doing this right after I wake up, because a while loop would be perfect, but it looks like textwrap may be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's an explained word wrap script, demonstrating how to write one.

I combined the final few words to make a really long one to demonstrate it dealing with that.

Hope you find this useful :)

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum."
length = 50

# split text into words
words = string.split(" ")

new = ""
for word in words:

    # Calculate length of current line
    current_length = len(new.split("\n")[-1])

    if len(word) <= length:
        if current_length + len(" ") + len(word) > length:
            # If the new word would take the line's length over the maximum

            # Add a new line and the word
            new += "\n" + word
        else:
            if current_length != 0:
                # to avoid adding a space at the start of the wrapped setence

                # Add a space between words
                new += " "
            new += word # Add the word on to the end
    else:
        # if the length of the word is already longer than the maximum

        # Break words into lines no more than (the maximum length - 1) chunks, and add a hyphen at the end
        new_word = '\n'.join([word[i:i+length-1] + "-" for i in range(0,len(word),length-1)])

        # Remove the final hyphen from the end
        new_word = new_word[:-1]

        # Add it onto the end
        new += '\n' + new_word

print(new)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident,suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimi-
destlaborum.
```